# Phrase which means to "code in" a programming language

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, verbs

What do you **do** with a *programming* language?

1. > I know C++, but it's been years since I last **worked with** it.
2. > I know C++, but it's been years since I last **worked on** it.

Of course, we could always use the seemingly more obvious (and safer) alternative:

3. > It's been years since I last **coded in** C++.

but that's not what I want.

**Is there any word/phrase which means to "code in" a programming language?**

Comment: In your examples, you could say it's been years since **I used it**.  I would avoid *since **I last worked on** it* because that implies that you were developing the language itself.  The short answer to your question at the top could be **develop**.  What you do with a programming language is **develop** applications or software.

Comment: What about the verb *write*? *'I wrote in C++'* seems natural to me

Comment: "written anything in it"

Comment: what @BladorthinTheGrey said.

Comment: anecdotally i feel like the phrase *work in <some language>* is related to *write in <some language>*, but maybe more specifically calling out professional experience

Answer (score 3):

I would use **use**.

Here is an example of this usage from an old [Bulletin Board post](http://www.verycomputer.com/20_682f9d1f50d220b3_1.htm):

> **‘It’s been years since I used Pascal”**

Comment: I like this one best.  "It's been years since I used Pascal."  Alternative: "I implemented the ABC algorithm for XYZ in Pascal."

Comment: Doesn't saying that I "use" a programming language brand the language as a mere object to use rather than a language to code in?

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine — Perhaps, but one could do worse, e.g. “Java used to pay the rent”. I had thought C++ was a fairly utilitarian language, but if you want to express an emotional involvement you could try something on the lines of “I used to self-actualize in Perl, but then I found peace in Python”. (But I wouldn’t recommend it.)

Answer (score 3):

"Wrote" is pretty commonly used in programming circles. Thus:

> It's been years since I wrote any C++.

Answer (score 1):

**Develop**

I wrote this earlier in a comment but I think it could be an answer to the question.

I would avoid **since I last worked on it** because that implies that you were developing the language itself.

The answer to "What do you do with a programming language?" is **develop**. What you do with a programming language is **develop** applications or software.

> It's been years since I last **developed** with C++

or

> It's been years since I last **used** C++ for **development**.

You're also correct that saying "coded" would be the most concise way to phrase the sentence, and is perfectly accurate and acceptable.

Comment: Doesn't saying that I "use" a programming language brand the language as a mere object to use rather than a language to code in?

Answer (score 1):

> What do you do with a programming language?

Why, you **[program](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/program)** in it, of course. However, that might not fit your intended use case, so you may prefer **use** (as already suggested).